# Замена кода применяемого в WPF в Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, winforms

Переношу код с WPF на Windows Forms и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть класс - который получает контекст от основного окна в конструктор.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   FFmpegConfig.UserInterfaceManager = new FFmpegUserInterfaceManager(this); 
   // Вот сюда.
}
```

Потом есть класс, который наследуется от абстрактного и реализует абстрактные методы:

```
public class FFmpegUserInterfaceManager : UserInterfaceManagerBase
{
    private Window parent;

    public FFmpegUserInterfaceManager(Window parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public override IUserInterface CreateUI(string title, bool autoClose)
    {
        return Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => FFmpegWindow.Instance(parent, title, autoClose));
    }

    public override void DisplayError(FFmpegProcess host)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => FFmpegErrorWindow.Instance(parent, host));
    }
}
```

Вот собственно вопрос, как мне на винформах получить инстанс, потому что строка

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => FFmpegErrorWindow.Instance(parent, host));
```

Не относится к контролам WinForms  и абсолютно не рабочая, после Application не видно например референс на Current.

Comment: `Переношу код с WPF на Windows Forms` зачем?

Comment: На WPF пример, а реализовать необходимо на формах. Не моя прихоть, так бы скопипастил демку и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас же есть `parent`, он какого типа?

- Если Window - то есть это всё ещё WPF и все должно работать.
- Если Form, то если весь UI у вас в одном потоке, то можно сделать так:

  ```
  parent.Invoke(new Action(() =>{ /*......*/ }));
  ```

Это запустит операцию в диспетчере, связанным с формой.

Comment: Спасибо! Нет у меня уже все Form `private MainForm _parent;

        public FFmpegUserInterfaceManager(MainForm parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }` А вот в лямбде как подменить `FFmpegWindow.Instance()`

Comment: @JDo значит вам надо использовать код, что я привел в ответе.

Comment: @JDo `А вот в лямбде как подменить FFmpegWindow.Instance()` вы не написали ни что это за функция, ни какая сигнатура у неё, ни что они делает. Я без понятия как её подменить :)

Comment: Я тут проглядел, Intance() - это статический метод, который получает в качестве параметра`Window parent`, а возвращает `FFmpegWindow F = new FFmpegWindow(); return F`. Вот такая сигнатура : `public static FFmpegWindow Instance(Window parent, string title, bool autoClose)` С экшеном не получается, так как студия говорит что тип обджекта не возможно кастить к `IUserInterface`.  Но в свою очередь в коде вопроса по идее через диспетчер возвращается окошко.

Comment: @JDo `Window parent` это WPF окно. Если вы не можете изменить этот метод, то вам нужно WPF окно, чтобы его туда отправить